# Using OR operator in XPath expression

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, domxpath

I want to use the OR condition (more than once) in my XPath expression to extract what I need in the content before a specific string is encountered, such as 'Reference,' 'For more information,' etc. The expression I have below doesn't seem to work when I'm using it in PHP, yet it works on an XPath tester. I would greatly appreciate any help. Also, can the expression be condensed?

```
"//p[starts-with(normalize-space(),'Reference')]/preceding-sibling::p | 
//p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'For more')]/preceding-sibling::p | 
//p[starts-with(normalize-space(),'Something')]/preceding-sibling::p"
```

Here's an example:

```
<root>
    <main>
        <article>
            <p>
               The stunning increase in homelessness announced in Los Angeles 
               this week — up 16% over last year citywide — was an almost  an 
               incomprehensible conundrum given the nation's booming economy 
               and the hundreds of millions of dollars that city, county and 
               state officials have directed toward the problem.
            </p>
            <p>
                "We cannot let a set of difficult numbers discourage us 
                or weaken our resolve" Garcetti said.
            </p>
            <p>
                For more information: Maeve Reston, CNN
            </p>
        </article>
    </main>
</root>
```

The result I'm looking for would be the following.

```xml
<p>
    The stunning increase in homelessness announced in Los Angeles
    this week — up 16% over last year citywide — was an almost  an
    incomprehensible conundrum given the nation's booming economy
    and the hundreds of millions of dollars that city, county and
    state officials have directed toward the problem.
</p>
<p>
    "We cannot let a set of difficult numbers discourage us
    or weaken our resolve" Garcetti said.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe is not exactly an "OR" - it allows you to use several alternative expressions. You could compare it to `UNION` in SQL. But it works in PHP.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = 
    "//p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Reference')]/preceding-sibling::p | 
     //p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'For more')]/preceding-sibling::p | 
     //p[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Something')]/preceding-sibling::p";

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
    echo $document->saveXML($node);
}
```

However "or" is allowed in Xpath conditions, actually:

```
$expression = 
    "//p[
      starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Reference') or 
      starts-with(normalize-space(), 'For more') or 
      starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Something')
    ]/preceding-sibling::p";

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
    echo $document->saveXML($node);
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/9SMJq

Comment: That you for that, that's a huge help. However, I think the sample I originally gave did not match the actual content I wanted to use it on. Can you take a look at my updated question and sample XML? Thanks!

Comment: I made a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550008/using-or-operator-in-xpath

Answer (score 0):

Normalize-space() won't work here because you are trying find sub-string.It is better to use contains.Try following xpath.

```
//p[contains(., 'For more')]/preceding-sibling::p
```

Example of or clause based on string.

```
//p[contains(., 'For more')]/preceding-sibling::p|//p[contains(., 'information')]/preceding-sibling::p|//p[contains(., 'CNN')]/preceding-sibling::p
```

Comment: And that too works in the XPath Tester but not in my PHP code, frustrating.

Comment: sorry I dont know about php however i thought you might problem of xpath so i have provided the solution.